# Why does accessing a member of a malloced array of structs seg fault?

Tags: c, memory-management, segmentation-fault, malloc

I am working through Learn C The Hard Way and am stumped on something.  I've written a simplified version of the problem I am running into to make it easier to get down to it:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#define GROUP_SIZE 10
#define DATA_SIZE 64

struct Dummy {
    char *name;
};

struct Group {
    struct Dummy **dummies;
};

int main() {
    struct Group *group1 = malloc(sizeof(struct Group));
    group1->dummies = malloc(sizeof(struct Dummy) * GROUP_SIZE);
    struct Dummy *dummy1 = group1->dummies[3];

    // Why does this seg fault?
    dummy1->name = (char *) malloc(DATA_SIZE);

    return 0;
}
```

When I try to set the name pointer on one of my dummies I get a seg fault. Using valgrind it tells me this is uninitialized space. Why is this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your *use* of `dummies` appears inconsistent with its *declaration*. From the way you use the `dummies` field it appears that `dummies` was intended as an *array* of `Dummy` structs, not an *array of arrays* of `Dummy` structs. If this is the case, change your declaration to this:

```
struct Group {
    struct Dummy *dummies; // Single asterisk
};
```

Then change your usage as follows:

```
struct Dummy *dummy1 = &group1->dummies[3];
```

Of course this assumes that `GROUP_SIZE` is four or more.

Answer (score 2):

you never malloced space for the `Dummy` itself. You need to do something like:

```
group1->dummies = malloc(sizeof(Dummy *) * GROUP_SIZE);
for(int i = 0; i < GROUP_SIZE; i++) {
   group1->dummies[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct Dummy));
}
```

Comment: I would say that @dasblinkenlight's suggestion (making this a contiguous allocation of `struct Dummy`s instead of double-indirection) is probably better.  (Unless you want to do something that double-indirection would actually be good for.)

Comment: @asveikau I was basing my answer on the fact that he had a `Dummy **dummies` in his `struct` and assumed that there was a reason for that.

Comment: So you started out by assuming the questioner understands why it's best to use double-indirection but *not* why it crashes when it's allocated as if it were a continuous allocation ...  :-)  My take is the questioner is probably new and it's best to introduce good practices, not show them how to implement Java-style memory layouts in C.

Comment: @twain249 thank you for your answer, it was the most unassuming.  Dasblinkenlight's assumption that I was actually going for an array of Dummies and not an array of arrays of dummies was correct. However, your answer did show me a few new tricks and helped my understanding of the problem as a whole, thanks.